# Select2: Getting ajax data attributes from selected value

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using Select2 4.0 as the code update has broken some existing code:

Data is loaded through an AJAX array structured as followed

['id':1,'text':'hello-world','artefact_type'=>'CONTACT'],
['id':2,'text':'test','artefact_type'=>'ORGANISATION'],

The plugin is configured as followed:

```
...
ajax: [
           'url' => $url,
           'dataType': 'json',
           'data' :'function(params) { return {q:params.term}; }',
           'processResults':'function(out) {console.log(out.results); return {results:out.results}; }',
      ],

templateResult: 'function(data) {
        return data.text+" - "+data.artefact_type;
}'
...
```

The AJAX is loading properly, as the template results displays both the text and artefact_type.

Now I try to implement the change function

```
function (e) {

  element  =  $("#quick-search");
  alert(element.val()+'++'+ e.val());
  artefact_type = ??;

if (data != "") {

    var url = "";
    if (artefact_type == "CONTACT") {
        url = "/xrm/contact/detail?id=" + element.val();
    }
    if (artefact_type == "ORGANIZATION") {
        url = "/xrm/organization/detail?id=" + element.val();
    }
    if (artefact_type == "COMMITTEE") {
        url = "/xrm/committee/detail?id=" + element.val();
    }
    $(location).attr('href', url);
}
else
{
    $("#test").html("Please select a sector operator...");
}
```

}

Previously I could do element.selected.artefact_type to achieve this.
How do I get the artefact_type corresponding to the selected value?
I am additionally not sure if data-attributes are actually being created.

Please help!
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by using $("#quick-search").select2('data')[0];

Same question was asked the day after:

[Adding "data-" attributes with select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940477/adding-data-attributes-with-select2/33948842#33948842)