# Adding "data-" attributes with select2

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I've seen a lot examples of `Select2` option tags set with "data-" attributes and I would like to do it.

I'm using ajax to get the data. I get the `ID` and the `TEXT` needed to build the select.

> But how can I add more attributes to it?

I just didn't find the way to add them.

```
$(element).select2({
    placeholder: 'Select one...',
    width: '100%',
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    ajax: {
        url: '/my/url',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function(params) {
            return {
                q: params.term,
                page: params.page
            };
         },
         processResults: function(data, page) {
             console.log(data);
             return {
                 results: data
             };
         },
         cache: true
     }
 });
```

Comment: If possible post you code..

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This solution applies to Select2 versions 4.0 or higher.

Assuming the attributes your talking about are loaded in the array you are returning in processResults. For example, if you are selecting a  record like ('id':1,'text':'some-text','custom_attribute':'hello world')

Then on a change event you can do:

```
data=$("#selector").select2('data')[0];
console.log(data.custom_attribute);//displays hello world
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: It just can't be better! Thanks!

Comment: What is the element you're targeting with $('#selector')?  Is that supposed to be the select2 dropdown?  Or the select2 'option' in the dropdown?  Something else?

Comment: @AaronHill, it has to be dropdown. You don't have many options to try. BTW. Thanks Jeffrey. I have no idea how did you find that but that's what I was looking for...

Comment: Note that in the change event `var data=$(this).select2('data')[0];` will get the value for the option selected i.e. `data.role` if you had that property in your source object

Comment: To clarify, the index of the selected element (this) would be `var ind = $(this).index();
var data=$(this).select2('data')[ind];`

Comment: Hi, can you post the complete code solution  ?

Answer (score 2):

select2 has an option called **templateSelection**

In the example below, I set another data field called 'staff_constant' on each option of my select2 element. I use `ajax` option because I get all the data from an endpoint.

Data structure:

```
{
  "id": 16471,
  "text": "Mmxmxm",
  "staff_constant": 6948
}
```

select2 instantiation:

```
$( ".select2" ).select2({
  // other option fields...

  // loading options from an endpoint
  ajax: {
    url: "{{route('customers.search')}}",
    type: "post",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
        search: params.term // search term
      };
    },
    processResults: function (response) {
      return {
        results: response
      };
    },
    cache: true
  },

  // I set `staff_constant` field here
  templateSelection: function (data, container) {
    $(data.element).attr('data-staff_constant', data.staff_constant);
    return data.text;
  },

  // other option fields...
});
```

Then I can access the selected option's staff_constant field like that

HTML

```
<select id="customer-field" onchange="selectStaff(this)" class="custom-select select2" name="customer" required>
</select>
```

JS

```
function selectStaff(e) {
  var staff_constant = $(e).find(':selected').data('staff_constant');
}
```

Further reading
https://select2.org/programmatic-control/retrieving-selections

Comment: You really saved my day bro!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you are asking but if you want to add data attribute you can do like this..

In Jquery:

```
$(element).attr('data-info', '222');
```

In javascript:

```
document.getElementById('elementId').setAttribute('data',"value: 'someValue'");
```

Comment: Yes, what it is exactly what  I want to do. But I want to do it inside Select2, because each `option` tag will have its own "data-something" attribute.

Comment: so you want to add `data-attribute` to all option. right?

Comment: Yes! Let's say that I want that all the options have the attribute `data-alias`

Comment: try this `$('#select option').attr('data-alias', 'yourvalue');`

Answer (score 1):

If your JSON response for `ajax` call looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "text": "option 1",
    "attr1": "custom attribute 1",
    "attr2": "custom attribute 2"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "text": "option 2",
    "attr1": "custom attribute 3",
    "attr2": "custom attribute 4"
  }
]
```

Then, select2 seems to add them as data attributes for option automatically,

And this is how you can access them, example in `change` event:

```
$(element).on('change', function(e) {
  console.log($(this).select2('data')[0]);
})
```

In above example, you can now access your json response as select2('data') attribute. example: `$(this).select2('data')[0].attr1` will return `custom attribute 1`

This way I was able to get data required data-attribute for selected option.

Comment: jishan `$(this).select2('data')` is not working for you? So basically, if you already have data attributes set for your select2 options, it will work, atleast working for me.

Comment: how to handle a default value when the new Option(name, id) has name and id attribute only ?

Comment: @MarkAnthonyLibres To set the default value, you can check https://select2.org/configuration/defaults docs.

Comment: the page does not showing how to set default value of select field, it is just literally configuration for select2

Comment: `$('#myselect option[value=10]').prop('selected', true).trigger('change');`, you can `trigger('change')` to let select2 know the field value is changed. @MarkAnthonyLibres

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set the `title` attribute of the `<option>` tag. This way the `select2('data')` function will return it.

This is a good approach when the select is build on the server side.