# select2 set option attributes manually for each option

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

i have `select2` dropdown like:

```
 <select class="form-control validateblank txtSelectChallan" id="txtSelectChallan" />
```

and i am setting `dropdown` data by `ajax` call like:

```
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Account/MaterialSheet.aspx/GetMaterialSheetByLedgerId",
    data: '{LedgerId: "' + AccId + '"}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.d.Result == "OK") {
            var challanresults = [];
            $.each(data.d.Records, function (index, challn) {
                challanresults.push({
                    id: challn.MaterialSheet_ID,
                    text: challn.Challan_No,
                    Amount: challn.Total_Amount
                });
            });

            eachtr.find('.txtSelectChallan').select2({
                placeholder: "Select Challan",
                data: challanresults,
                multiple: true
            });
            swal.close();
            challanresults = null;
        }
    },
    error: function (err) {
        swal(
           'Oops...',
           'Error occured while retrieving data',
           'error'
         );
    }
});
```

and i get `dropdown` like :

```
<select class="form-control validateblank txtSelectChallan select2 hidden-accessible" id="txtSelectChallan" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" multiple="">
  <option value="1006">123123</option>
  <option value="1007">32123</option>
```

i have tried to set `option` attribute using:

```
             challanresults.push({
                    id: challn.MaterialSheet_ID,
                    text: challn.Challan_No,
                    Amount: challn.Total_Amount
                });
```

but i cant get amout as `option` attribute any idea how to set custom attribute for all `option` in `select2`?

Comment: which version are you using

Comment: i have used Select2 4.0.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this inside foreach loop, and set the trigger after that.

```
var data = {
id: challn.MaterialSheet_ID,
text: challn.Challan_No
};

var newOption = new Option(data.text, data.id, false, false);
$('#txtSelectChallan').append(newOption).trigger('change');
```

[Check this link for further solution on custom attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940477/adding-data-attributes-with-select2)

Or Simply you can do like this in a loop for the result set
`var option =  "<option value="+challn.MaterialSheet_ID+" amount="+challn.Total_Amount+">"+challn.Challan_No+"</option>`

This is what Select2 Official Site has to say about custom-data-fields

```
$('#mySelect2').select2({
// ...
templateSelection: function (data, container) {
// Add custom attributes to the <option> tag for the selected option
$(data.element).attr('data-custom-attribute', data.customValue);
return data.text;
}
});

// Retrieve custom attribute value of the first selected element
$('#mySelect2').find(':selected').data('custom-attribute');
```

[Click here for the above reference link](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/retrieving-selections)

Comment: If doesn't help then you can simply create a html tag using string and pass the parameters and values

Comment: how to add with html tag??

Comment: ok but in link you have provided their answers could't understand by me

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/milz/4f1syu2a/ check this fiddle here you can see the customData is added and on change it can match with customData when the value is red

Comment: Also check this official select2 site for the same : https://select2.org/programmatic-control/retrieving-selections

Comment: yes I think so or you can try the last edit made in the answer if it helps else last option would be the manual one I suggested before as I can see in most of the cases people has shown the way to retrieve than a way to add.

Comment: Hope I was able to help you :)